# Dividing each element of a python dataframe to a Series

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like below:

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = {"a":[1.,3.,5.,2.],
     "b":[4.,8.,3.,7.],
     "c":[5.,45.,67.,34]}
data2 = {"a":[4., 6, 8]
     }

df = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
```

So each element of `df` should be divided by the first row of `df2` until all.

What I did:

```
df = df.divide(df2, axis=0 )
```

It gives me all the rows as `NAN`. Can you tell me what is wrong?

expected output:

```
       a         b       c
0  0.250  1.000000   1.250
1  0.500  1.333333   7.500
2  0.625  0.375000   8.375
3  2.000  7.000000  34.000
```

Comment: How looks expected ouput?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exact output that you expect is unclear, but if I guess correctly, you might want to only divide the common indices/columns and leave the rest untouched.

For this you can use [`combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) to fill the NaNs after the division:

##### column "a" only:

```
df.div(df2, axis=0).combine_first(df)
```

##### all columns:

```
df.div(df2['a'], axis=0).combine_first(df)
```

or [`reindex_like`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex_like.html) and [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) to align the dataframes before division.

##### column "a" only

```
df.div(df2.reindex_like(df).fillna(1), axis=0)
```

output (column a only):

```
       a    b     c
0  0.250  4.0   5.0
1  0.500  8.0  45.0
2  0.625  3.0  67.0
3  2.000  7.0  34.0
```

output (all columns):

```
       a         b       c
0  0.250  1.000000   1.250
1  0.500  1.333333   7.500
2  0.625  0.375000   8.375
3  2.000  7.000000  34.000
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df.div(df2.reindex(df.index).fillna(1).reindex_like(df).ffill(1))
```

out:

```
       a         b       c
0  0.250  1.000000   1.250
1  0.500  1.333333   7.500
2  0.625  0.375000   8.375
3  2.000  7.000000  34.000
```

Comment: Please provide more insight to your code, explain what each function does and how.